# Using multiple variables in a for loop

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to use two variables in a `for` loop like this (This is for example, I'm not going to execute `seq` like operations)

```
for i j `seq 1 2` 'www.google.com www.yahoo.com';do echo $i $j;done
```

Expected output is

> 1  www.google.com
>
> 2 www.yahoo.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If *i* was to just be a number that incremented with each string, you could try a *for* loop and increment *i* with each iteration.

For example:

```
i=1; for j in 'www.google.com' 'www.yahoo.com'; do echo "$((i++)) $j"; done
```

Comment: why did you, use double braces in `$((i++))`. I think one braces is enought for this. Please correct me , If i said wrong.

Comment: @SuperKrish `$(( . . .))` is arithmetic expansion, which is what makes `i++` work. With single braces that's `$(. . .)` command substitution , so `i++` won't work there. If you were trying to catch output of another program, say `$( df )` for example, you could use single braces. If you need calculation, then you use `$(( . . . ))` structure

Comment: Great! @jake My doubt is clear

Answer (score 4):

Lets create variable to point to the file location

`FILE="/home/user/myfile"`

The file content:

```
www.google.com 
www.yahoo.com
```

To get the output of:

```
1 www.google.com
2 www.yahoo.com
```

It can be done by one of the following methods below:

---

Using counter variable:

```
i=1; 
cat $FILE | while read line; do 
    echo "$((i++)) $line"; 
done
```

---

Using `cat -n` (number all output lines)

```
cat -n $FILE | while read line; do 
    echo "$line"; 
done
```

---

Using array:

```
array=(www.google.com www.yahoo.com);
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do 
    echo "$((i+1)) ${array[$i]}"; 
done
```

---

If your file already with line numbers, example:

```
1 www.google.com
2 www.yahoo.com
```

Loop and split every line to array:

```
cat $FILE | while read line; do
    col=( $line ); 
    echo "${col[0]} ${col[1]}"; 
done
```

---

For more info:

- [How to increment a variable in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash)
- [Loop Through Array of Strings in Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-array-of-strings-in-bash-script)
- [Arrays Syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some alternative ways, two short and simple ones:

```
 printf "%s\n" www.google.com www.yahoo.com | cat -n
```

and

```
 for i in www.google.com www.yahoo.com; do echo $i; done | cat -n
```

which both output:

```
 1  www.google.com
 2  www.yahoo.com
```

and the slightly more complex:

```
s=(www.google.com www.yahoo.com)
for i in $(seq 1 ${#s[@]}); do
        echo $i ${s[i-1]}
done
```

that outputs:

```
1 www.google.com
2 www.yahoo.com
```

In that second suggestion, I'm using an array named `s` created with the line `s=(xx yy)`

The `${#s[@]}` syntax is the number of elements in the array, here `2` and the `${s[i-1]}` is element at offset `i-1` from the beginning of the array, thus `${s[1-1]}` is `${s[0]}` and then is `www.google.com`, etc.

---

Comment: I dont know what is means `${#s[@]}`  `${s[i-1]}1. Here s is the variable loaded with some values.Can you clear my doubt?

Comment: Answer edited with explanations added.