# how to extract MAC data from grep and insert into bash

Tags: bash, grep, syntax

I'm trying to extract the MAC address for a wireless card then insert it into a bash script as a VAR variable with an incremental change.
So..

```
$ ifconfig wlan1 | grep HWaddr
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:xx:XX:xx:XX:xx
```

Now I need to command line extract just the XX:xx:XX:xx:XX:xx and add it to the script with a +1 VAR .  Which seems pretty straight forward if I can extract just the XX:xx:XX:xx:XX:xx from the grep above.
(ie [How to increment a variable in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash) )

Can anyone see a roadblock to adding a MAC address as a variable in a bash script?  ie without bash thinking the MAC is a string calculation or erroneous command ?

Comment: Do you want a bash script to change 11:11:11:11:11:11 to 11:11:11:11:11:12 ?

Comment: If you capture the MAC address into a variable, you won't be able to just increment the variable, as the MAC address is a string. You could take the last 2 digits of the string as a different variable, then increment that, and replace the last 2 digits with it.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by incrementing the MAC address by one. Give a real (or real-looking) example and show us how you'd like to change it.

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to read the MAC from the appropriate file within the `sys` filesystem. If you call your variable mymac, then:

```
$ mymac=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan1/address)
```

Should work

```
$ echo "mymac"
XX:xx:XX:xx:XX:xx
```

It would be possible to increment the value of the last digits with a bit of variable manipulation. **This will only work if they are both digits with a value of 98 or less.** The following example uses an assumed MAC of 52:1c:53:8b:8f:77.

```
$ endpair=${mymac##*:}
$ ((endpair++))
$ newmac="${mymac%:*}:${endpair}"
$ echo "Hooray $mymac is now $newmac"
Hooray 52:1c:53:8b:8f:77 is now 52:1c:53:8b:8f:78
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245925/7222080) provides a portable solution (it'll work on Unix, generally, not just Ubuntu), and should provide resiliency if the output format of `ifconfig` changes ([or if it's deprecated/removed](https://serverfault.com/a/633089/388491) and you decide to switch to a different tool).

```
ifconfig wlan1 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

Comment: It might be worth changing `eth0` in your code to `wlan1` as that's the interface the OP is interested in.

Comment: Well spotted! I actually had to change it from `en0` (testing on a Mac) - embarrassing I made the wrong change...

Comment: Although Ubuntu often uses the consistent device naming thing these days so it could be anything like en2p0!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more commands for extracting only the MAC Address.

I suggest you use awk and print only the last column, example:

```
ifconfig wlan1 | grep HWaddr | awk '{ print $5 }'
```

This command will show only XX:xx:XX:xx:XX:xx, awk print $5 split lines by spaces.

If you want add this result in bash variable, you need apply this command:

```
myVarName=$(ifconfig wlan1 | grep HWaddr | awk '{ print $5 }')
```

Then, you use this content with $myVarName.

```
echo $myVarName
XX:xx:XX:xx:XX:xx
```

Comment: You can avoid spawning `grep` by using a pattern in `awk`: `myVarName=$(ifconfig wlan1 | awk ' /HWaddr/ { print $5 }'`