# script error for while loop

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts

I'm getting the below error while i executing the bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

mynum=1

while [ $mynum -le 10 ]
do
    echo $mynum
    mynum= $(( $mynum + 1 ))
    sleep 0.5
done
```

error:

```
$./wl
1
./wl: line 8: 2: command not found
1
./wl: line 8: 2: command not found
1
./wl: line 8: 2: command not found
1
./wl: line 8: 2: command not found
1
./wl: line 8: 2: command not found
1
./wl: line 8: 2: command not found
1
./wl: line 8: 2: command not found
1
./wl: line 8: 2: command not found
```

Comment: The error is due to the space between `mynum= ` and `$(( $mynum + 1 ))` which is causing the shell to try to execute `2` (the result of `$(( $mynum + 1 ))`) as a separate command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way for incrementing variable is as follows ([How to increment a variable in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385528/how-to-increment-a-variable-in-bash))

```
#!/bin/bash
mynum=1
while [ $mynum -le 10 ]
do
    echo $mynum
    mynum=$((mynum+1))
    sleep 0.5
done
```