# Bash terminal to list commands from folder containing text files

Tags: command-line, bash

Hello I want to create an interactive bash file while using a text file how can I make it work like if the user presses 1 it gives him a full list of names from this text file
For example I'm struggling in

1. List all
2. Display Info
3. Count Students
4. Delete Student
5. Backup
6. Exit
   List all: if the assistant choose this option, information (first line of each file) about all the
   students is displayed, one student per line, sorted in alphabetical order according to student
   surname.

Display Info: if the assistant choose this option, a file containing all Students ID, Major and GPA
is created and displayed (one student per line).

Delete Student: if the assistant choose this option, he/she will prompted to enter the ID of the
student to delete its file from the database. Add conditions to check the valid format for student
ID (9 digits long).Return a warning message if the ID doesn’t exist.

Count: if the assistant choose this option, the number of students per major is displayed in a
reverse numerical number.

Backup: if the assistant choose this option, a backup folder for the students’ database is created
with the date, at the time of the operation, added to the name of the folder
2
(CurrentStudents.Date). The date must have the following format
day_FullMonthName_Last2DigitsYear.

Exit: if the assistant choose this option, the program terminates.

Also,The menu is displayed again after each option except the Exit option which terminates the
program.
Any invalid choice from the menu, will display a message informing the user of the invalidity of
the choice and prompts for it again.
There are two ways to end the program normally: either by having the user choose the Exit option
or when an invalid choice is entered more than 3 times.
Help is really appreciated

Comment: You probably need something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233621/conditioning-script-question/1233636#1233636)

Comment: And I want a pony. What have you tried? Have you considered what to do if "the user" presses something other than "`1`", like "qwertyuiop"?

Comment: How do i make it like a menu 1- 2- then when the user presses one of them it makes a command then the menu returns again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this as a template:

```
#!/bin/bash

menu () {
echo "Please choose a command below"
echo "  1)Print Present workind directory"
echo "  2)echo hi"
echo "  3)Clear screen"
echo "  4)Exit menu" 
}

menu

while read n

do

case $n in
  1) echo "$PWD";;
  2) echo "hi";;
  3) clear;;
  4) exit;;
  *) echo "invalid option. Please try again";;
esac

menu

done
```

Comment: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `echo' it returns for me this error also i need this menu to pop up each time the user opens the scripy